# ERROR 404 encountered when attempting to call a servlet

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

i'm attempting to use apache tomcat 7.0 tomcat7 to access java servlets.

I have created a folder to hold all my webapp files under the ROOT folder in webapps.
The file structure is like this.

- Tomcat 7.0/webapps/myWebApp

  - **HelloHome.html**
  - WEB-INF

    - **web.xml**
    - classes

      - com

        - training

          - HelloServlet.java
          - **HelloServlet.class**

to call the servlet this web.xml code was used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

   <!-- To save as "hello\WEB-INF\web.xml" -->

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.training.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <!-- Note: All <servlet> elements MUST be grouped together and
         placed IN FRONT of the <servlet-mapping> elements -->

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/sayhello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the actual java code (compiled to generate a class file under the classes folder):

```
//To save as "<TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes\HelloServlet.java"
package com.training;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException, ServletException {

      // Set the response MIME type of the response message
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      // Write the response message, in an HTML page
      try {
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head><title>Hello, World</title></head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");  // says Hello
         // Echo client's request information
         out.println("<p>Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Protocol: " + request.getProtocol() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>PathInfo: " + request.getPathInfo() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Remote Address: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</p>");
         // Generate a random number upon each request
         out.println("<p>A Random Number: <strong>" + Math.random() + "</strong></p>");
         out.println("</body></html>");
      } finally {
         out.close();  // Always close the output writer
      }
   }
}
```

i then hit: **http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/sayhello**
and get a 404 error. any ideas as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your servlet must not be in the default package. Put it in a package, update your web.xml with the new package info.

Comment: placed my class file in a package. classes -> com -> training -> HelloServlet.class. Also updated the web.xml file's <servlet-class> tag to <servlet-class>com.training.HelloServlet</servlet-class>. still 404 error.

Comment: The directory structure is completely unclear in the question: please fix it so it's legible by making it monospaced and indenting properly.

Comment: The comment in the web.xml about grouping is incorrect, btw.

Comment: edited the directory structure and the web.xml <servlet-class> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myWebApp should live next to ROOT, not inside of it.

[Tomcat 7 Deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)

Comment: i tried doing that but simply hitting http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/ generates a 404 error

Comment: restart tomcat... , add hellohome.htm to welcome-file list & make it load http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/sayhello. Then try localhost:8080/myWebApp

Comment: If you use only /myWebApp it will look for a file in the welcome-file-list which should be in your web.xml, it will not automatically pick up your HelloHome.html neither your servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Put your myWebApp.war file under webapps folder instead of ROOT, restart Tomcat and then try the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your servlet in a package, and register it in web.xml accordingly.
I remember I've encountered this issue with older version tomcat a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

ROOT will be having tomcat demo applications,
put your myWebApp folder in $tomcat_home/webapps     (not inside ROOT)

restart tomcat & try the same URL

Answer (score 0):

edit your web.xml file and add this below tag:

<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>/sayhello</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>